# File ended while scanning use of \frame

Tags: beamer, errors, environments

I am a beginner in Latex.

My code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Green]{structure}

\title[HUM-THE SABHAl]{Training And Placement Cell}
\subtitle{Industrial Training Report }
\author{MADE BY-\bigskip\\Mudita Tripathi\\1150810904\\Heena Tabassum\\1050810017\\Amandeep Kaur\\1050810007\\Anoop Kumar singh\\1050810009\\Sameeksha Tandon\\1050810042}
\institute{BBDESGI,CS-4}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of contents}

    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{ABSTRACT}
    \begin{frame}{ABSTRACT}
        \begin{block}{}

                \begin{itemize}
                        \item The national website , "HUM-THE SABHA" , is designed to address the problems of comman man\bigskip.
                        \item It presents a virtual parliament on the internet\bigskip.
                        \item  It is an easy to interact website whereby the public can easily interact and retreive the dezired information\bigskip.
                        \item The website is designed to deliver all sorts of political information needed for the overall development of the country and to satisfy the needs of the people\bigskip.
                \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}



\section{INTRODUCTION}
    \begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Our website displays several departmental works to make people aware of the official proceedings\bigskip.
                \item We have given provisions about good work appreciation, undertaken by people. This will create competence among the people for consideration of their problems\bigskip.

                                         \item There is a law and order section in our website where the registered users can attain several information about our constitution\bigskip.
                                         \item The registered users can also address their problems in this section.

            \end{itemizeir dedication towards development\bigskip.
                                           \item To address the government with the necessities of the comman man\bigskip.
                                           \item To bring out new enthusiastic leaders and support them in their nation development movement .

            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
        \end{block} 
    \end{frame}

\section{MISSION}
    \begin{frame}{OBJECTIVES}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item To Screen out all political parties and th
    \end{frame}

\section{TOOLS USED}
    \begin{frame}{TOOLS USED}
        \definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}
            \begin{itemize}
                \fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
                \color{DarkBlue}
                                    \item \textbf{Hardware Requirements:}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont
                    \item  Processor                                :     Pentium Dual Core
                                                  \item  Ram                                        :     2 GB
                                               \item   Hardware Disk Requirement   :     80 GB\bigskip
                \end{itemize}
                                           \fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
                                           \color{DarkBlue}
                \item \textbf{Software Requirements:}
                \begin{itemize}

                    \item Operating Sytem                     :  Windows 8
                                                      \item Back End                                 : SQL Server
                                                      \item Front End                               : ASP.Net 
                                                   \end{itemize}
                \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}


\section{PROJECT DIVISION}
    \begin{frame}{PROJECT DIVISION}

            \begin{figure}{}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.65]{lfc.jpg}
            \end{figure}

    \end{frame}

\section{ADMIN PANEL}
    \begin{frame}{ADMIN PANEL}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Admin login \bigskip
                \item Students detail record.\bigskip
                \item Generate list for selected companies.\bigskip
                \item Calculate placement percentage.\bigskip
                \item Make announcements.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\section{USER PANEL}
    \begin{frame}{USER PANEL}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Enter detail of each student \bigskip
                \item Update student detail \bigskip
                \item Generate students contact detail for each year and each department.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\section{WORKING AND SCREENSHOTS OF THE PROJECT}
    \begin{frame}{WORKING AND SCREENSHOTS OF THE PROJECT}

            \centerline{\huge \textcolor{blue}{WORKING AND SCREENSHOTS}} 
            \bigskip
            \centerline{\huge \textcolor{blue}{OF THE PROJECT}}
    \end{frame}

\section{LOGIN PAGE}
    \begin{frame}{LOGIN PAGE}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item This is the homepage of the application. \bigskip
                \item On the page several links are given to go to other pages of the website \bigskip
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{figure}{}
        \bigskip
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd1.png}
    \end{figure}

\section{STUDENT LOGIN PAGE}
    \begin{frame}{STUDENT LOGIN PAGE}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item The left side includes a view detail link to view the student details.
                \item The right side includes important posts and below it is the query section where students can ask any query regarding placement.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{figure}{}
        \bigskip
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd2.png}
    \end{figure}

\section{STUDENT DETAIL PAGE}
    \begin{frame}{STUDENT DETAIL PAGE}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item When a student wants to see the record , he / she can click on the view button on the homepage and the student detail page will appear. \bigskip
                \item This page includes information like : year , branch ,student resume  , achievements , name , ID.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{figure}{}
        \bigskip
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd3.png}
    \end{figure}

\section{ADMIN LOGIN PAGE}
    \begin{frame}{ADMIN LOGIN PAGE}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item After admin login, the admin login page will appear. \bigskip
                \item This page includes links like: enter notice where the manager can enter the important details about the companies , placement notifications etc.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{figure}{}
        \bigskip
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd4.png}
    \end{figure}
\begin{figure}{}
        \bigskip
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{preparation.PNG}
    \end{figure}
\begin{frame}{company}
\begin{figure}{}
        \bigskip
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{home2.PNG}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\section{CONCLUSION}
    \begin{frame}{CONCLUSION}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item The project has been developed using VISUAL STUDIO. \bigskip
                \item Project attention has been given to make this project user friendly.\bigskip
                                          \item It successfully stores all the details submitted by the students as well as admin.\bigskip
                                          \item Every new entry in the database will send a mail to the aspirants.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\section{FUTURE SCOPE}
    \begin{frame}{FUTURE SCOPE}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item This application can be modified from time to time as per the changing user requirements with less cost.\bigskip
\item The limitation with this application can be looked into and the enhancement can be made as per the requirement.        
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\section{LIMITATIONS}
    \begin{frame}{LIMITATIONS}
        \begin{block}{}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item The only limitation of this project is that it connects us to the database and make the details about training and placement accessible to the students only according to the branch.\bigskip
\item It has to be according to marks eligibility.\bigskip
\item Rest the project satisfies all the project objectives.       
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\section{}
    \begin{figure}{}
            \bigskip
            \centering
                \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{t1.jpg}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I suspect the error is somewhere here:

```
\section{PROJECT DIVISION}
        \begin{frame}{PROJECT DIVISION}

                \begin{figure}{}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=0.65]{lfc.jpg}
                \end{figure}

        \end{frame}
```

But can't figure out the exact problem.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: We need a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I know you're a beginner, but it's bad practice on this site to just dump a long code and ask for people to find where the errors come from. You have to do a bit of work first, namely, isolate the error, perhaps by commenting out parts of the code and see whether that solved the problem.

Comment: There seem to be typos (e.g., `\end{itemizeir` in the frame called Introduction) and duplicated statements (e.g., `\end{block}` in the same frame) throughout the document. You need to go through the material one frame at a time.

Comment: You also have `\end{block}` twice in a row in the third frame; that can't be good.

Comment: @Jubobs I know it's not a good practice to post code like that, and I myself try to avoid that. But, since I did not know exactly where the error came from, I posted the whole code. I am really sorry and thankful to you for correcting the whole code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code contains several "dangling" environments, e.g. a `\begin{itemize}` without a matching `\end{itemize}`, or an `\end{block}` without a matching `\begin{block}`; those cause `beamer` to throw errors, which, unfortunately, are not very informative, because they usually don't tell you where those "dangling" environments are.

However, systematic code formatting promotes smooth debugging: for instance, if you indent your code as I did, spotting a "dangling" environment will be comparatively easier.

Other problems remain in your code (and mine): abuse of `\bigskip`, lack of maintainability, use of illegal tokens in `\author`, contents outside frame environments even though you don't seem to be using `beamerarticle`, etc.; but none of them prevent you from compiling, now.

```
\documentclass[
  xcolor=dvipsnames,
  %demo, % <--- I only use this option to be able to compile your code without having the graphics file; remove it to remove the black boxes
]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{lmodern}        % <--- those two packages help when you use
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % the default font LaTeX font


\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Green]{structure}

\title[HUM-THE SABHAl]{Training And Placement Cell}
\subtitle{Industrial Training Report }
\author{MADE BY-\bigskip\\Mudita Tripathi\\1150810904\\Heena Tabassum\\1050810017\\Amandeep Kaur\\1050810007\\Anoop Kumar singh\\1050810009\\Sameeksha Tandon\\1050810042}
\institute{BBDESGI,CS-4}

\setbeamertemplate{items}{\vspace{-1em}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of contents}
      \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}


\section{ABSTRACT}

  \begin{frame}{ABSTRACT}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item The national website , "HUM-THE SABHA" , is designed to address the problems of comman man\bigskip.
        \item It presents a virtual parliament on the internet\bigskip.
        \item  It is an easy to interact website whereby the public can easily interact and retreive the dezired information\bigskip.
        \item The website is designed to deliver all sorts of political information needed for the overall development of the country and to satisfy the needs of the people\bigskip.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}


\section{INTRODUCTION}

  \begin{frame}{INTRODUCTION}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Our website displays several departmental works to make people aware of the official proceedings\bigskip.
        \item We have given provisions about good work appreciation, undertaken by people. This will create competence among the people for consideration of their problems\bigskip.
        \item There is a law and order section in our website where the registered users can attain several information about our constitution\bigskip.
        \item The registered users can also address their problems in this section.
            ir dedication towards development\bigskip. % <--- there was a problem here (\end{itemizir ...)
        \item To address the government with the necessities of the comman man\bigskip.
        \item To bring out new enthusiastic leaders and support them in their nation development movement .
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block} % <--- there was a second \end{block} here
  \end{frame}


\section{MISSION}

  \begin{frame}{OBJECTIVES}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item To Screen out all political parties and th
      \end{itemize} % <--- this itemize environment was left open
    \end{block} % <--- this block environment was left open
  \end{frame}


\section{TOOLS USED}
  \begin{frame}{TOOLS USED}
    \definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}
    \begin{itemize}
      \fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
      \color{DarkBlue}
      \item \textbf{Hardware Requirements:}
        \begin{itemize}
          \fontsize{13pt}{13pt}\selectfont
          \item Processor                    :     Pentium Dual Core
          \item Ram                          :     2 GB
          \item Hardware Disk Requirement    :     80 GB\bigskip
        \end{itemize}
      \fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont
      \color{DarkBlue}
      \item \textbf{Software Requirements:}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Operating Sytem              :  Windows 8
          \item Back End                     : SQL Server
          \item Front End                    : ASP.Net 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}


\section{PROJECT DIVISION}

  \begin{frame}{PROJECT DIVISION}
    \begin{figure}{}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{lfc.jpg} % <--- you can't pass the value 0.65 to width
                                                      % because width expected a ``dimension''
                                                      % (you probably meant 0.65 times the text width)
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}


\section{ADMIN PANEL}

  \begin{frame}{ADMIN PANEL}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Admin login \bigskip
        \item Students detail record.\bigskip
        \item Generate list for selected companies.\bigskip
        \item Calculate placement percentage.\bigskip
        \item Make announcements.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}


\section{USER PANEL}

  \begin{frame}{USER PANEL}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Enter detail of each student \bigskip
        \item Update student detail \bigskip
        \item Generate students contact detail for each year and each department.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}


\section{WORKING AND SCREENSHOTS OF THE PROJECT}

  \begin{frame}{WORKING AND SCREENSHOTS OF THE PROJECT}
    \centerline{\huge \textcolor{blue}{WORKING AND SCREENSHOTS}}
    \bigskip
    \centerline{\huge \textcolor{blue}{OF THE PROJECT}}
  \end{frame}


\section{LOGIN PAGE}

  \begin{frame}{LOGIN PAGE}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item This is the homepage of the application. \bigskip
        \item On the page several links are given to go to other pages of the website \bigskip
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{figure}{} % <--- content outside a frame environment... why?
    \bigskip
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd1.png}
  \end{figure}


\section{STUDENT LOGIN PAGE}

  \begin{frame}{STUDENT LOGIN PAGE}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item The left side includes a view detail link to view the student details.
        \item The right side includes important posts and below it is the query section where students can ask any query regarding placement.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{figure}{} % <--- content outside a frame environment... why?
    \bigskip
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd2.png}
  \end{figure}


\section{STUDENT DETAIL PAGE}

  \begin{frame}{STUDENT DETAIL PAGE}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item When a student wants to see the record , he / she can click on the view button on the homepage and the student detail page will appear. \bigskip
        \item This page includes information like : year , branch ,student resume  , achievements , name , ID.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{figure}{} % <--- content outside a frame environment... why?
    \bigskip
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd3.png}
  \end{figure}


\section{ADMIN LOGIN PAGE}
  \begin{frame}{ADMIN LOGIN PAGE}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item After admin login, the admin login page will appear. \bigskip
        \item This page includes links like: enter notice where the manager can enter the important details about the companies, placement notifications etc.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{figure}{} % <--- content outside a frame environment... why?
    \bigskip
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{bbd4.png}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}{} % <--- content outside a frame environment... why?
    \bigskip
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{preparation.PNG}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{frame}{company}
    \begin{figure}{}
      \bigskip
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{home2.PNG}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}

\section{CONCLUSION}

  \begin{frame}{CONCLUSION}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item The project has been developed using VISUAL STUDIO. \bigskip
        \item Project attention has been given to make this project user friendly.\bigskip
        \item It successfully stores all the details submitted by the students as well as admin.\bigskip
        \item Every new entry in the database will send a mail to the aspirants.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}


\section{FUTURE SCOPE}

  \begin{frame}{FUTURE SCOPE}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item This application can be modified from time to time as per the changing user requirements with less cost.\bigskip
        \item The limitation with this application can be looked into and the enhancement can be made as per the requirement.        
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}


\section{LIMITATIONS}

  \begin{frame}{LIMITATIONS}
    \begin{block}{}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item The only limitation of this project is that it connects us to the database and make the details about training and placement accessible to the students only according to the branch.\bigskip
        \item It has to be according to marks eligibility.\bigskip
        \item Rest the project satisfies all the project objectives.       
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}


\section{}

  \begin{figure}{}
    \bigskip
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.98\linewidth]{t1.jpg}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```